# Save Output of PHP Virtual() to String

Tags: php

Is there a way to get the Output from PHP Virtual()?

```
ob_start()
virtual();
ob_end_flush();
```

is in my case not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.virtual.php:

> To run the sub-request, all buffers are terminated and flushed to the
>   browser, pending headers are sent too.

One way that I can think of is to create a separate file and load that:

```
// virtual.php
virtual('/path/to/whatever');
```

Then wherever you want to get the contents, load it up:

```
// other.php
$string = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/path/to/virtual.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

You use `obj_end_flush()` which stops output buffering and deletes buffered output.
What you would probably want is this:

```
ob_start();
virtual();
$output = ob_get_clean();
```

`$output` contains the buffered output because `ob_get_clean()` stops output buffering and returns the buffered output instead of deleting it.

[PHP manual `ob_end_flush()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-flush.php)

[PHP manual `ob_get_clean()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php)